# Uploadify progress bar flashing (jumping)

Tags: php, uploadify

I have problem with progress bar in uploadify plugin. 
Files are uploaded correctly, percents are displayed also correctly, but progress bar is like jumping from 0% to approx. 10%, then again 0% to approx. 15% and so on up to approx 50%.

Has anybody had similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last project I had problem you describing. I had used uploadify before and it had been working fine. Change was version of jQuery. Using jQuery 1.7 the problem exists so I moved back to 1.6.2 and problem disappeared. Hope it helps you.

EDIT
After some testing with 1.6.2 version I found another small tweaks with progress bar so I really recommend staying with 1.4.2 jquery version under which uploadify works well.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too.  The problem is that, apparently, the newest version of jQuery animates css width changes using pixel values when you use percentages.  I set up a test case to confirm.

I didn't want to use an old version of jQuery, so I fixed the uploadify code.

https://gist.github.com/dayer4b/a8698725e4513cf34e61

I just added some logic to use the percentage to calculate the pixel width necessary for the progress bar.  Then use that pixel value instead of the percentage.